# How to show data from database to jtable with checkboxes in the first column in jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know how to populate jtable and i had prepared the code for the above which works fine. But the problem is that it is working in another project but bot in my current project. The code for both the project is same. Here is the code... purchaswtab is the table name which has been already created using swing palette. And this function is executed in the event of the exit button of the Item Master.
the array elements of an array ap are defined as i have to fetch them from the given position from the resultset.

```
public void populatetable(ItemMaster imm)
{
    imm.dispose();
    String t[][]=new String [30][10];
    int[] ap={19,1,2,4,18,16,17};
    Object[] h1=new Object[7];
    String a1,a2;
    int j=0,i=1;
    int len=0;
    try
     {            
        st=fun.connect1();           

        String query="select * from Temp_Purchase";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);       

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int k=0;
            for(i=1;i<=7;i++,k++ )
            {
                t[j][i-1]=rs.getString(ap[k]);
                System.out.println(t[j][i-1]);
            }
            j++;
            len++;
        }

        fun.close();
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        fun.close();
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }

    DefaultTableModel de=(DefaultTableModel)purchaseTab.getModel();
    purchaseTab=new JTable(de);



    //Code for filling data into table

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=7;j++)
        {                
            h1[j-1]=t[i][j-1];
        }

        if(h1[0]=="0")
        {         
            h1[0]=Boolean.FALSE;         
        }
        de.insertRow(i,h1);            
    }
    //jsp.setViewportView(Table);
}
```

Comment: *How to show data from database to jtable with checkboxes in the first column in jtable?* Are there booleans stored in first column? If so then you need to override `getColumnClass(int c)` method to return `Boolean.class` for the first column since `DefaultTableModel` implementation returns `Object.class`. Then the cell renderer/editor will be a check box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- replace evetything inside `while(rs.next())` to `de.addRow(new Object[..., ..., ...]);`
- you have to declare `DefaultTableModel de` as local variable, initialized before `fun` is called
- then to pass `DefaultTableModel de` to `JTable`, e.g. `myTable(de);` or `myTable.setModel(de)`
- use `Object[]` instead of limitations for `String[]`, then you can to [store various data type in `DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: I am understanding what you are saying but I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code as it is working fine in another project. And you had given me suggestions so i believe that you must found something wrong in my code. Please let me know about it.

Comment: JTable has similair structure and logics as Database, each row from  database is separate row in JTable, then every loop should be creating a new Object[], to put all Object[]s together is Object[][] corresponding with JTables view or database view, shortcut  search for TableFromDatabase or ResultSetTableModel

Answer (score 0):

From @mKorbel's answer

Create and add a DefaultTableModel like:

```
DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Here data is double vector and header is single vector.

```
data = get(field);
Object[] d={data.get(i).get(0),data.get(i).get(1),data.get(i).get(2)};
model.addRow(d);
```

Get data from database

```
get(field){
//Your Database connection
//Get data into vector
//return vector
}
```